# WebPack resolves a module to an object instead of a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have `entry-point.js`, `First.js`, `Second.js` in the same directory.

**entry-point.js**

```
var First = require('./First.js'); // If I take out this line the error will go away.
var Second = require('./Second.js');

Second();
```

**First.js**

```
var Second = require('./Second.js'); // And if I take out this line the error will go away.

module.exports = () => {
  console.log('FIRST')
};
```

**Second.js**

```
var First = require('./First.js');

module.exports = () => {
  First();
};
```

When I compile `entry-point.js` with a very basic webpack configuration (there is really nothing much, I don't even want to pollute the question with it) I get the error `First is not a function`. I guess it is because there are some recursive dependencies, but I can't really wrap my head around that.

P.S. I somewhat know how to fix it, I just want to realize why exactly it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the circular dependencies: `First` depends on `Second` and `Second` depending on `First`.

This is due to having a dependency cycle, and are assigning `module.exports` to a new object at the end of the file.

Due to the cycle, the `module.exports` object is passed to `Second` on the first line of `First`, this is an empty object.

After this, `First` reassigns the value of `module.exports` to a function, but the object has already been passed to `Second`, which is why you get the error.

To solve this, eliminate the circular dependency if you can. Circular dependencies are confusing and usually a symptom of tightly coupled code, it would be best to modularize your functions in a way that common dependencies are extracted to their own modules.

If you can't eliminate circular dependencies, you will need to **avoid reassigning `module.exports`**.

#### First.js:

```
var Second = require('./Second.js');

module.exports.first = () => {
  console.log('FIRST')
};
```

#### Second.js

```
var First = require('./First.js');

module.exports = () => {
  First.first();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you require `First` in `entry-point`, loader starts loading `First.js` and that requires `Second.js`. As `First` is not fully finished loading so it is a empty object, that's why you get `not a function` error.

There are lot of ways to fix circular dependency problem. One way is to add a file with all the imports and then require from it.

```
//dependecy.js

var First = require("./First")
var Second = require("./Second")

exports.First = First
exports.Second =Second


//First.js

var {Second} =require("./dependency")

//Second.js
var {Frist} =require("./dependency")
```